# Safari iOS changing SVG fill gradient url

Tags: css, svg, mobile-safari, gradient, fill

in the footer of my site I have social icons as SVGs that fill depending on screen size and hover state.

One example is for instagram:
HTML:

```html
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/pacific_beach_homes/" title="Visit our Instagram page" target="blank" >
  <svg class="instagram" alt="Instagram icon" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>Instagram</title>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="ig-gradient">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F8ED34" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#EA118D" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#2E368F" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path d="M12 0C8.74 0 8.333.015 7.053.072 5.775.132 4.905.333 4.14.63c-.789.306-1.459.717-2.126 1.384S.935 3.35.63 4.14C.333 4.905.131 5.775.072 7.053.012 8.333 0 8.74 0 12s.015 3.667.072 4.947c.06 1.277.261 2.148.558 2.913.306.788.717 1.459 1.384 2.126.667.666 1.336 1.079 2.126 1.384.766.296 1.636.499 2.913.558C8.333 23.988 8.74 24 12 24s3.667-.015 4.947-.072c1.277-.06 2.148-.262 2.913-.558.788-.306 1.459-.718 2.126-1.384.666-.667 1.079-1.335 1.384-2.126.296-.765.499-1.636.558-2.913.06-1.28.072-1.687.072-4.947s-.015-3.667-.072-4.947c-.06-1.277-.262-2.149-.558-2.913-.306-.789-.718-1.459-1.384-2.126C21.319 1.347 20.651.935 19.86.63c-.765-.297-1.636-.499-2.913-.558C15.667.012 15.26 0 12 0zm0 2.16c3.203 0 3.585.016 4.85.071 1.17.055 1.805.249 2.227.415.562.217.96.477 1.382.896.419.42.679.819.896 1.381.164.422.36 1.057.413 2.227.057 1.266.07 1.646.07 4.85s-.015 3.585-.074 4.85c-.061 1.17-.256 1.805-.421 2.227-.224.562-.479.96-.899 1.382-.419.419-.824.679-1.38.896-.42.164-1.065.36-2.235.413-1.274.057-1.649.07-4.859.07-3.211 0-3.586-.015-4.859-.074-1.171-.061-1.816-.256-2.236-.421-.569-.224-.96-.479-1.379-.899-.421-.419-.69-.824-.9-1.38-.165-.42-.359-1.065-.42-2.235-.045-1.26-.061-1.649-.061-4.844 0-3.196.016-3.586.061-4.861.061-1.17.255-1.814.42-2.234.21-.57.479-.96.9-1.381.419-.419.81-.689 1.379-.898.42-.166 1.051-.361 2.221-.421 1.275-.045 1.65-.06 4.859-.06l.045.03zm0 3.678c-3.405 0-6.162 2.76-6.162 6.162 0 3.405 2.76 6.162 6.162 6.162 3.405 0 6.162-2.76 6.162-6.162 0-3.405-2.76-6.162-6.162-6.162zM12 16c-2.21 0-4-1.79-4-4s1.79-4 4-4 4 1.79 4 4-1.79 4-4 4zm7.846-10.405c0 .795-.646 1.44-1.44 1.44-.795 0-1.44-.646-1.44-1.44 0-.794.646-1.439 1.44-1.439.793-.001 1.44.645 1.44 1.439z"/></svg>
     </a>
```

CSS:

```css
.instagram {
    fill: #fe4164;
    fill: url('#ig-gradient');
    
}
```

I included a backup color above the fill:url(...) because I thought this might fix it if Safari doesn't accept gradient fills. But that is not the problem. It seems that safari is actually changing the url from what is typed in the css file.

On most browsers, the fill: url(#ig-gradient); is working fine. However Safari for iOS is different. . .

Safari for iOS is changing the fill url to a full url link: url(https://pacificbeachhomes.com/wp-content/themes/pacificbeachhomes/#ig-gradient) which doesnt work, instead of url(#ig-gradient) which works. .. .

Anyone know why safari for iOS is adding the domain? I tried putting the fill url in quotes (shown above) and without quotes and it doesnt seem to change.

active site is: [pacificbeachhomes.com](https://pacificbeachhomes.com)

Comment: This question is similar and has some notes about the fill url not being supported on Safari. . . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051351/svg-gradient-using-css