# How do I get the xpath for SVG element with linearGradient defs?

Tags: url, svg, xpath, exide

I am trying to find the xpath for the following SVG rectangle element with lineargradient attribute stop-color="#FFFFFF".

I can certainly retrieve the xpath by referencing the attribute @fill=url(#color1) but I want to do it by the color code #FFFFFF. It is confusing to do so as the URL() function is not resolving in eXide. Any advice is very much appreciated.

```
<body>
  <svg>
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="color1">
        <stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="color2">
        <stop stop-color="#000000" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <svg x="10%" y="10%" width="10%" height="10%">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#color1)" />
    </svg>
  </svg>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This xpath should get the element as expected

```
//svg[defs/linearGradient/stop[@stop-color="#FFFFFF"]]/svg/rect
```

Testing on command line with `xmllint`

```
xmllint --xpath '//svg[defs/linearGradient/stop[@stop-color="#FFFFFF"]]/svg/rect' tmp.html
```

Returns

```
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#color1)"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! But I am not looking for the lineargradient element - this wouldn't point to the rectangle element. Any idea how I can find the rect element that has fill="url(#color1)" but using #FFFFFF instead?

Comment: Fixed the xpath to get `rect` element.

Comment: Done! :-) Another question, how do I also select the child (circle with color1) of the rect element? Updated the input in my question above.

Comment: `//svg[defs/linearGradient/stop[@stop-color="#FFFFFF"]]/svg/svg/circle`

Comment: Sorry to be bothering you on this. What about selecting both the rect+circle? I couldn't seem to do it with the descendant-or-self axis - it would display the rects and not circle.

Comment: `//svg[defs/linearGradient/stop[@stop-color="#FFFFFF"]]/svg/rect | //svg[defs/linearGradient/stop[@stop-color="#FFFFFF"]]/svg/svg/circle`

Answer (score 1):

I agree to LMC.

But your svg code is incomplete.
It doesn't work as a self contained .svg file (alwas a good starting point to check, wether your svg specific markup results in an expected display).
You missed to define starting and end color stops.

Try this:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="color1" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f00" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <svg x="10%" y="10%" width="10%" height="10%">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#color1)" />
    </svg>
</svg>
```

See also: [SVG gradient using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051351/svg-gradient-using-css)

Comment: Thank you, will take note :-) The question is more on Xpath for me.