# Is it possible to fill an svg with a gradient color or background image?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have this Instagram svg logo and I want to change it's color to either a linear-gradient or a background image on hover, is it possible using css?
I've tried:

```css
#instagram:hover {
  fill: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}
```

```html
<svg fill="#000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id={stylesFooter.instagram} viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="240px" height="240px">     <path d="M 8 3 C 5.243 3 3 5.243 3 8 L 3 16 C 3 18.757 5.243 21 8 21 L 16 21 C 18.757 21 21 18.757 21 16 L 21 8 C 21 5.243 18.757 3 16 3 L 8 3 z M 8 5 L 16 5 C 17.654 5 19 6.346 19 8 L 19 16 C 19 17.654 17.654 19 16 19 L 8 19 C 6.346 19 5 17.654 5 16 L 5 8 C 5 6.346 6.346 5 8 5 z M 17 6 A 1 1 0 0 0 16 7 A 1 1 0 0 0 17 8 A 1 1 0 0 0 18 7 A 1 1 0 0 0 17 6 z M 12 7 C 9.243 7 7 9.243 7 12 C 7 14.757 9.243 17 12 17 C 14.757 17 17 14.757 17 12 C 17 9.243 14.757 7 12 7 z M 12 9 C 13.654 9 15 10.346 15 12 C 15 13.654 13.654 15 12 15 C 10.346 15 9 13.654 9 12 C 9 10.346 10.346 9 12 9 z"/>
</svg>
```

```css
#instagram:hover {
  fill: url(image);
}
```

```html
<svg fill="#000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id={stylesFooter.instagram} viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="240px" height="240px">     <path d="M 8 3 C 5.243 3 3 5.243 3 8 L 3 16 C 3 18.757 5.243 21 8 21 L 16 21 C 18.757 21 21 18.757 21 16 L 21 8 C 21 5.243 18.757 3 16 3 L 8 3 z M 8 5 L 16 5 C 17.654 5 19 6.346 19 8 L 19 16 C 19 17.654 17.654 19 16 19 L 8 19 C 6.346 19 5 17.654 5 16 L 5 8 C 5 6.346 6.346 5 8 5 z M 17 6 A 1 1 0 0 0 16 7 A 1 1 0 0 0 17 8 A 1 1 0 0 0 18 7 A 1 1 0 0 0 17 6 z M 12 7 C 9.243 7 7 9.243 7 12 C 7 14.757 9.243 17 12 17 C 14.757 17 17 14.757 17 12 C 17 9.243 14.757 7 12 7 z M 12 9 C 13.654 9 15 10.346 15 12 C 15 13.654 13.654 15 12 15 C 10.346 15 9 13.654 9 12 C 9 10.346 10.346 9 12 9 z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: there is no `id=instagram` in the code you posted. You can target the fill by using something like: `path { fill: black; }` ... so no ID needed for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051351/svg-gradient-using-css

Comment: @cloned I am using css modules in react js so the id is  id={stylesFooter.instagram} as for #instagram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by having the gradient within the SVG:

```css
#instagram:hover path {
  fill: url(#myGradient);
}
```

```html
<svg fill="currentcolor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="instagram" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="240px" height="240px">
  <path d="M 8 3 C 5.243 3 3 5.243 3 8 L 3 16 C 3 18.757 5.243 21 8 21 L 16 21 C 18.757 21 21 18.757 21 16 L 21 8 C 21 5.243 18.757 3 16 3 L 8 3 z M 8 5 L 16 5 C 17.654 5 19 6.346 19 8 L 19 16 C 19 17.654 17.654 19 16 19 L 8 19 C 6.346 19 5 17.654 5 16 L 5 8 C 5 6.346 6.346 5 8 5 z M 17 6 A 1 1 0 0 0 16 7 A 1 1 0 0 0 17 8 A 1 1 0 0 0 18 7 A 1 1 0 0 0 17 6 z M 12 7 C 9.243 7 7 9.243 7 12 C 7 14.757 9.243 17 12 17 C 14.757 17 17 14.757 17 12 C 17 9.243 14.757 7 12 7 z M 12 9 C 13.654 9 15 10.346 15 12 C 15 13.654 13.654 15 12 15 C 10.346 15 9 13.654 9 12 C 9 10.346 10.346 9 12 9 z"/>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="myGradient">
       <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#F60" />
       <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#FF6" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```